# Google Apps Script widget in Google Site opens links in new tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a Google Apps Script UiApp that I am embedding in a Google Site. The App contains anchors, which are declared like so:

```
app.createAnchor("Back to Everyone", ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?page=1").setTarget("_self");
```

When running this as a standalone web app, the new page opens in the same tab in the browser as expected because of the setTarget("_self"). However, when running the app from within a Google Site, the links open in a new tab, and google redirect 'are you sure' message is seen.

Is there a way I can ensure links open in the same tab when running a Google Apps Script UiApp within a Google Site ?

Thanks

Comment: I really doubt it. But let's wait and see if someone got a little magic :)

Comment: The Google redirect message is browser specific and can be changed in the browser settings.

Comment: Nice to know @Srik... browser settings, hum. Care for a link? :)

Comment: Have you tried [_parent or _top](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)?

Comment: Both _parent and _top don't work